# Есть ли ограничение на получение почты по POP3?

Tags: pop3, email

Подключился по POP3 к ящику Gmail. Писем очень много, но скачивает клиент только по 300-400 штук и прекращает. Приходится опять включать отправку-подключение и опять закачивает небольшую порцию. Это ограничение Gmail? Как загрузить без ограничения все письма?

Comment: Загрузки идут объемом по 4.25 Мб.

Comment: Время показало, что объем загрузок колеблется примерно от 3 до 12 мегабайт. Писем ходит от примерно от трехсот до полутора тысяч.